# Why doesn't WP recognize images in posts like other content?

Tags: css, core

I've noticed a problem I have with images in my posts: they seem to go unnoticed to my CSS.

For example, I have a span tag that is adding a 100px margin to the top of itself under the last paragraph in each post.

But when an image is present the span tag seems to ignore the image as part of the paragraph content.  There is no 100px margin created.

I'd usually say this is a CSS problem... but I think it may be a WP problem.  Any thoughts?

[Website](http://themeforward.com/demo2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you've floated your image on line 745 of your CSS.

You've cleared the span, but the margin property still won't if there's a floated element above...

Change the margin to padding, that should fix it..